# OpenERP OpenObject processes

Tags: odoo

I read about [processes](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/7/7_18_Process/index.html) and I think they are a great help to users. Now I want to create a process for my experimental module. I'm looking into sale_process.xml and the first record references the sale module. Where is can I find `model_sale_order`?

```
<record id="process_process_salesprocess0" model="process.process">
    <field eval="1" name="active"/>
    <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
    <field eval="&quot;&quot;&quot;Sales&quot;&quot;&quot;" name="name"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's pointing to the `ir_model_data` record with name 'model_sale_order' and module 'sale'. That record in turn points to the `ir_model` record for the sale_order table that has a child record for each field. All of these records are generated based on the details defined in the [`sale_order` class](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/6769/sale/sale.py#L49). One of the key features of each model class is the [`_columns` dictionary](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/6769/sale/sale.py#L199). The developer documentation has a pretty good description in its chapter on [Objects, Fields, and Methods](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/index.html).

If you are adding a few fields to the standard 'sale.order' model (inheriting), then your module will use the same 'sale.model_sale_order' record and just add a few more child records for your new fields. You can continue to reference 'sale.model_sale_order' when you add to the process definition.

If you are creating a separate model and not inheriting, then don't use the 'sale.order' name in your model class. Use a name like 'mysale.order'. That will automatically generate a new 'mymodule.model_mysale_order' record, and you can reference that in the process definition.

Comment: I was looking at sale_order class and I didn't find anything. In _columns I can't find nothing that start with the word "model". If the class somehow generate column model_sale_order, I think it supposed to be present in database as column?

Comment: 'model_sale_order' is just a name, @MarioŽupan, that other modules can use to refer to the `sale_order` table and its details. It's not a column. I tried to clarify my answer a bit.

Comment: Where is defined that name? I want to change it, for example to my_model.

Comment: I think, @MarioŽupan, that the name is automatically generated based on the model class's name. So the 'sale.order' class would generate a record called 'model_sale_order', and the 'account.invoice' class would generate a record called 'model_account_invoice'. I don't think you can change it, and I'm not sure why you would want to.

Comment: I copy the whole class sale.order to the my module try to reference to mymodule.sale_order and got error after I refresh and try to install my module. ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: mymodule.sale_order I want to figure out how to create a process for my module.

Comment: I added an explanation of the difference between inheriting an existing module, and creating a new one, @MarioŽupan. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much Don on your patience. I finally got it. You must admit that whole situation isn't so clear for a newbie with the python. It doesn't matter. You were of a great help.

Comment: OpenERP is a very tough project for newbies, @MarioŽupan. I've tried to contribute back some improvements to [the documentation](https://launchpad.net/openobject-doc), but there's a long way to go.